# Hide rows based on userform text box values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form with two text boxes ... the text boxes allow the user to input a 'from' and 'to' value.
I would like to hide all rows where cell value in column "AH" is greater or equal to 'from' value and less than or equal to the 'to' value.

I tried the following but, I get no hidden rows?

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range

LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "AH").End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Range("AH3:AH1000")

    If (c.Value >= UserForm1.TextBox1.Value And c.Value <= UserForm1.TextBox2.Value) Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

I added an else code ... this works OK providing I state the from and to values (as below).
but, I cannot reference the values in my text boxes. When I try to use the line below with the reference to `UserForm1.TextBox1.Value` and `UserForm1.TextBox2.Value` the code runs but does nothing ?

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range

LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "AH").End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Range("AH3:AH1000")

    If (c.Value >= 0 And c.Value <= 1500) Then
    '(c.Value > UserForm1.TextBox1.Value And c.Value < UserForm1.TextBox2.Value) Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Else: c.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll kick yourself... Change

```
c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

to

```
c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Comment: I have amended my code but, still have issues with the userform.textbox.value reference - please see edited question.

Comment: Can you step through the code and pause it when you find a value you expect it to work at and see the values being returned are? One possible cause is that Excel might be assuming a text format when you have numbers. You could try: If (c.Value * 1 >= 0 And c.Value * 1 <= 1500) Then

Comment: Hi. this is what I don't understand ... when I step through the code the value of c is equal to the cell value, UserForm1.TextBox1.Value is equal to the textbox1 value and UserForm1.TextBox2.Value is equal to the textbox2 value. However the textbox values are shown in quotations ... I'm using the text boxes for numeric values - do I need to change the textbox values to numeric ?

Comment: Thanks for you help Dave. I converted the text box values to integers and the code works ... CInt(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value)